# Next.js app not running in background when launched using PM2

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2, next.js13

I have a small web application made using Next.js. Since the app is running on a server where another Node app is running, I decided to use PM2 to manage them more easily.

In my root folder i made an `ecosystem.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: 'signature',
      script: 'npm',
      args: 'start',
      interpreter: 'none',
      env: {
        NODE_ENV: 'production'
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

And this is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "signature",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "clipboard": "^2.0.11",
    "dompurify": "^3.0.6",
    "next": "latest",
    "react": "latest",
    "react-dom": "latest",
    "react-toastify": "^9.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "latest",
    "postcss": "latest",
    "tailwindcss": "latest"
  }
}
```

From the server, I try to start the app using `pm2 start ecosystem.config.js`, the command opens a node terminal (which I'm not sure is supposed to appear since the app should run in the background with PM2) where I can see that the app is running on the server:

```
> signature@0.1.0 start
> next start

  ▲ Next.js 13.5.3
  - Local:        http://localhost:3000

 ✓ Ready in 332ms
```

While the node terminal is open, `PM2 list` outputs this:

```
E:\signature>pm2 list
┌────┬──────────────┬─────────────┬─────────┬─────────┬──────────┬────────┬──────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ id │ name         │ namespace   │ version │ mode    │ pid      │ uptime │ ↺    │ status    │ cpu      │ mem      │ user     │ watching │
├────┼──────────────┼─────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼──────────┼────────┼──────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 0  │ signature    │ default     │ N/A     │ fork    │ 3316     │ 85s    │ 0    │ online    │ 0%       │ 0b       │ admindpi │ disabled │
└────┴──────────────┴─────────────┴─────────┴─────────┴──────────┴────────┴──────┴───────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

The PM2 list output is the same when i close the node terminal, except the app stops working (which I guess makes sense)

Answer (score 0):

Try to using this ecosystem.config.js file

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: 'signature',
      script: 'node_modules/next/dist/bin/next',
      args: 'start',
      interpreter: 'none',
      env: {
        NODE_ENV: 'production'
      }
    }
  ]
};
```